# How to find an actor having max earnings per movie in Neo4j db?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate-functions, aggregation, graph-databases

I need to write a query to find the actor having max earnings per movie in Neo4j db.

I have written below query:

```
match (a:Person)-[role:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
return m.title as Movie, max(role.earnings) as earnings
```

This gives me the `max earning` in a movie.

**How to find the actor corresponding to that max earning?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two alternatives.

Match again and look for the actor/actors that had max earnings:

```
match (a:Person)-[role:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
with m, max(role.earnings) as earnings
match (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN{earnings:earnings]->(m)
return m.title as Movie, earnings, a.name as actor
```

Sort and take first item in collection:

```
match (a:Person)-[role:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
with m, role.earnings as earnings, a.name as actor order by earnings
return m.title as Movie, collect(earnings)[0] as earnings, collect(actor)[0] as actor
```

Some additional questions to consider:

- How do you want to handle if two actors have the same earnings?
- Can one actor play multiple roles in the same movie/have earnings per ACTED_IN relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort/collect the movie, earnings and actor by earnings in descending order. Then get the first item in the collection.

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[role:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH m, role.earnings as earnings, a ORDER BY earnings DESC
RETURN m.title as Movie, collect(earnings)[0] as earnings, collect(a.name)[0] as actor
```